# Using partial OSM map limitations?

Tags: openstreetmap

Before I setup OSM I need to choose between host the planet or just a section of it. I would prefer the first one, but I'm afraid of the effect that this will have.

Is there an option to get only a few countries on my machine, and the request for other titles being relayed to other server? Or they will just not appear on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host the planet or just some countries, it's possible.
The manual how to setup a OSM server: http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/

It's only depend on your server capacity.

Comment: Thanks! I don't need it any longer, and I suppose that when I asked this, there was no way yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any ready-to-use solution. Because a rendered map usually consists of square [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) you would have to define some rather complex comparisons for each single tile to decide whether to retrieve it from your own server or a different one.